# Installing new python modules doesn't always work

Tags: python

I am facing difficulties in installing new modules in `python`. Not always, but in most of the cases.

This happens for two main reasons; I am newbie and I have multiple `python` versions installed on my laptop. For instance, this module [here](http://packages.python.org/pyenchant/) works through terminal, however, it doesn't work through `eclipse`. In addition, this module [here](https://bitbucket.org/spirit/guess_language) doesn't work at all. So my question is: from where should I start so as to solve the problem?

Comment: What OS are you on currently?  That may affect the suggestions, at least mine for sure.

Comment: @nerdwaller I am using Ubuntu Linux 12.04

Answer (score 1):

Why you don't use [PyPI](http://pypi.python.org/pypi)? The Python Package Index is a repository of software for the Python programming language. There are currently 26536 packages here. So pypi is a easiest way to install new python module.

Answer (score 0):

You have several option. If you are running a redhat distro, then you can try to do an install via `yum`. If for the none standard distro version then you might have copy folders from the site-packages folder into the other.

Other options you have are pip, easy_install, and PyPI. Google will tell you the rest.